# Асинхронное изменение элемента в BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Для хранения массива использую сервис, в родительском компоненте делаю For массива и передаю в дочерний компонент элемент массива, Массив BehaviorSubject, на обоих компонентах стоит стратегия Onpush, 
Изнутри дочернего компонента вызываю метод изменяющий элемент массива через сервис. 
Так вот если изменения производить сразу, то в дочернем компоненте изменения отрисовываются, а если сделать задержку то нет.

Помогите найти корень проблемы

Накидал пример в stackbiz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vywwsb

Answer (score 0):

Решение предоставил [Християн Христов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7177558/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD-%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2):

Here is the solution [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7mnyk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I assume the problem is related to some bug involving the immutability of `immutable.js` and angular's change detection. The fix that I applied is just to pass the data coming from the stream trough a function that creates and returns new object, so that ngChangeDetection can be triggered.

*In the following code sinppet data is **BehaviorSubjec**t of **immutable.js** `List` `BehaviorSubject(List(array_of_objects));`

Перевод:

Я предполагаю, что проблема связана с некоторой ошибкой, связанной с неизменностью `immutable.js` обнаружения изменений углов и углов. Исправление, которое я применял, - это просто передать данные, поступающие из потока, через функцию, которая создает и возвращает новый объект, так что может быть запущено ngChangeDetection.

- В следующем коде данные sinppet - **BehaviorSubjec**t of **immutable.js** `List BehaviorSubject(List(array_of_objects));`

```js
// OLD
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of (data |async );
                trackBy: trackByFn;
                let first = first">
            {{item['list'].send}}
            <app-item [item]="item" [first]="first"></app-item>
</ng-container>

//FIX
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of (data |async );
                trackBy: trackByFn;
                let first = first">
            {{item['list'].send}}
            <app-item [item]="func(item)" [first]="first"></app-item>
</ng-container>

//WHERE func

func(obj){
return ({...obj})
}
```